# Bootstrap Tabs - trigger tabs by href link (how to trigger tab view in addition to hitting the tab itself)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

For my projects section on my website I have them laid out in tabs. I have an overview tab that shows small cards with images of each of the projects. I would like to enable a feature where clicking on a project card will make "active" the respective tab.

I copied the format of the tabs by setting the following on my project card divs:

```
<a href="#Tab_Content_ID" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
    <div id="Project_Image"></div>
</a>
```

I am able to trigger the opening of that project's tab. However, the tab itself (in the tab navbar) is not selected. The overview tab is still selected (active) and thus the user can not return to the overview without first clicking on another project tab then back to the overview tab.

How can I fix this?

Project [link](http://www.vampiire.org)
This is the current live version of the page. It does not reflect the changes I have made because they are still in testing. Just linking here so you can get a visual idea of what I'm talking about.

Relevant Projects Section HTML [link](https://gist.github.com/the-vampiire/98003fb279f4b1528d588ec13b970acb)
I can't post it in a codepen because none of the images will show.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I doubt anyone will ever read this but I solved it myself. Now to be fair this is somewhat specific to my ID system but here goes

Each tab is a list item in the unordered list of the nav-tab bar. This is important because the "active" class is placed on the LIST item not the TAB itself.

Each tab content has an ID which I have titled "Project-Tab" where Project is the name of that particular project.

Each tab then links (href) to the content of that tab with an ID I have titled "Project" where project is the name of that particular project.

Now in my overview section on each of the "project cards" that I have linked to the tab content I added a class "Overview_Tab"

With that explanation here is the solution

```
 $('.Overview_Tab').click(function(){

/* Gets the href of the clicked "project card" which is a link to the tab 
   content for that project. I then concatenate '-Tab' onto the end to get the 
   id of the associated tab (as explained above) */

     var target = $(this).attr('href')+'-Tab';

// Get the parent (the list item containing that tab div) this is where 
   "active" needs to be placed 

     var target_parent = $(target).parent();

// Remove the active class on the overview tab 
     $('#Overview-Tab').parent().removeClass('active');

// Add active class to the target parent 
     target_parent.addClass('active');

});
```

So to generalize this you want your tab ID and tabContent ID to be the same just add '-Tab' to the end of your tab ID.

Pick any class name you want to add to the element that is replicating a tab (I picked "Overview_Tab" but you can put anything there as long as it matches between the HTML and the JS function)